# mysqli.cache_size in php.ini | how to use it?

Tags: mysql, php, php.ini

My company has an Apache server running PHP 5.4. My task is to update it to PHP 7.4.

The old php.ini file includes a `mysqli.cache_size` property. I can't find any documentation on this property. Does it still exist in PHP 7? Could anyone link me to the documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest it is not useful enough to be documented.  I see a similar property for PDO and the now-defunct mysql APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pdo_mysql.cache_size` INI directive is removed (it has been unused since PHP 5.3.0 due to a bug): https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2777